# Is it possible to customise the buildSrc project?

Tags: gradle

Gradle outputs all the build sub-project generated files into buildSrc/build - I don't want that stuff being dumped in the middle of my source tree.

So, "is it possible to customise the buildSrc project output location"?

I've looked through the doco and it seems like you can really only customise the external dependencies of the buildSrc project from your build.gradle file.  I'm thinking if this can be changed it would be in the settings.gradle or an init-script - but I can't find much in the way of documentation or examples for those.

P.S. - I know what an ignore file is - that's not the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is: add a buildSrc/build.gradle with content:

```
buildDir = "where-ever you want it to go"
```